# Retrieving token from APNS-php error

Tags: php, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to implement APNS-PHP, and discovered that in my test environment I have a few invalid tokens (as the test devices moved to production).

I need to get the token ID from a serialized object in an array, as I want to catch this scenario and remove the invalid tokens form the DB. I use the following code, but that doesn't work:

```
    $aErrorQueue = $push->getErrors();
    if (!empty($aErrorQueue)) {
        foreach($aErrorQueue as $error){            
            foreach($error['ERRORS'] as $err){
                $message .=  $err['statusMessage'] . " ";
                if($err['statusCode'] == 8){
                    $phones = Phone::getPhonesWithToken($error['MESSAGE']['_aDeviceTokens:protected'][0]);
                    Phone::setToken($phones[0]['id'], "");      
                }
            }   
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the APNS_Message is the serialized object in $error['MESSAGE'], and I cannot remember how to access the token in that object...

Var dump:

> ["MESSAGE"]=>
>   object(ApnsPHP_Message)#9 (8) {
>   ["_bAutoAdjustLongPayload:protected"]=>
>   bool(true)
>   ["_aDeviceTokens:protected"]=>
>   array(1) { [0]=> string(64)
>   "018E4B9CB8CF73341CE4EBE7138E25E605CD80FB74B3A9701CE5CCA6D9363F3A"
>   } ["_sText:protected"]=> NULL
>   ["_nBadge:protected"]=> int(256)
>   ["_sSound:protected"]=> NULL
>   ["_aCustomProperties:protected"]=>
>   NULL ["_nExpiryValue:protected"]=>
>   int(604800)
>   ["_mCustomIdentifier:protected"]=>
>   string(17) "Message-Badge-004" }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$error['MESSAGE']->_aDeviceTokens[0]`

Comment: I just realised that! A stupid mistake, and shows I haven't used PHP for some time!

Answer (score 2):

`_aDeviceTokens` is a protected property, you will find that accessing this property directly will throw an exception.

You should instead use the `getRecipients()` or `getRecipient($recipientNumber = 0)` method on the `Message` object to retrieve the device token(s).

For example:

```
$token = $error['MESSAGE']->getRecipient();
```